# Convert $\sin 2x$ into terms of $\cos 2x$

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I need to convert a factor of $\sin 2x$ into terms of $\cos 2x$, or any power of $\cos 2x$. Basically I need to solve an equation by substituting $r = \cos 2x$ and solve for $r$, but I am stuck with a factor of $\sin 2x$, and I am not able to get rid of it. Is it even possible?

I have managed to find that

$$
\sin 2x = \frac{2\cos 2x \tan x}{1 - \frac{1 - \cos 2x}{1 + \cos 2x}}
$$

but now I'm stuck with a tangent function.

Obviously I tried using

$$
\sin 2x = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 2x}
$$

but that only gives the positive values of the sine function, and I need all values.

## Update after 5 years

I should of course have added more information when I opened this question all these years ago. I came up with a solution, which was briefly outlined in my MSc thesis (in chemistry, not mathematics). Screenshot below.

[image]

and equation 2:

[image]

Comment: Put the question here for a better understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to do.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have some equation you are trying to solve with expression for $\sin(2x)$? Probably you are on a wrong way. $\sin(2x)$ is not representable as a polynomial function of $\cos(2x)$. Beware of http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: The only way to change $\sin 2x$ in terms of  $\cos 2x$ is that $\sin 2x=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2 2x}$. Take two cases, one for the + and one for -  and then solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have any limitation on $x$?

Answer (score 0):

We know,

$\sin^2 2x + \cos^2 2x = 1$

$\cos^2 2x = 1 - \sin^2 2x$

$\cos 2x = \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 2x}$

Comment: How could I implement the $\pm$ into the solution of an equation? Do I get a set of two equations?

Comment: Yes $x^2 = 1 \to x = \pm 1$. As x is quadratic not linear.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can say $\sin(2x) = \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(2x)}$,
consider each of the $+$ and $-$ cases separately, and see which values of $x$ give you solutions to the original equation.

Or you can look for alternative approaches. If one technique is not looking good, try another for a bit. Maybe you will end up returning to the first technique, but maybe you will find the solution a different way.

If you were going to go with your first attempt, you can still make it a lot simpler, because
$$
1 - \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}
= \frac{(1 + \cos(2x)) - (1 - \cos(2x))}{1 + \cos(2x)}
= \frac{2 \cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}
$$

and therefore
$$
\frac{2\cos(2x) \tan x}{1 - \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}}
= 2\cos(2x) \tan x \left(\frac{1 + \cos(2x)}{2 \cos(2x)}\right)
= (1 + \cos(2x))\tan x.
$$

You could apply the half-angle tangent formula to get rid of the tangent:
letting $\theta = 2x,$
$$
\tan x = \tan\frac\theta2 = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta}}
= \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}},
$$
but this is not obviously better than $\sin(2x) = \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(2x)}$.

Another possible technique is to use $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ instead,
using $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$ and $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2 x - 1$
and hoping that the extra $\sin x$ gets canceled somehow.

But more likely the solution is to take another step back into the larger problem that you have not shown us and to look for a way that does not require directly solving the equation in $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$ that you thought you had to solve.

You cannot get any help with the larger problem if you present only a very tiny glimpse into just one step of your (so far unsuccessful) attempt to solve the larger problem. That is why one of the comments referred to the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).